# Power BI Paginated Reports / SSRS : Repeat tables for each customer

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I'm trying to create a Paginated Report in PBI Report Server.
Below is the layout that I want to achieve.

the table1 and table2 should be repeated for each customer dynamically.
All the data is coming from same dataset (i.e. single table)

Any help would be appreciated.

---

### Customer#1
attribute1

### Table1

---

### Table2

---

### Customer#2
attribute1

### Table1

---

### Table2

Below is how the final output should look like in Paginated Report

[image]

Below is sample data

| limit_instrument_desc | limit_time_band_desc | limit_original_amount | customer | gib_rating | sp_rating | moodys_rating | group_industry_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total Exposure | 1Y | 766996330.805987 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | 1Y | 894384273.139102 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | Inf | 186847061.527764 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| UnsignedExpo | 1Y | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Treasury | 1Y | 73674799.171963 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Money Market | 1W | 148988667.957832 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Money Market | 1M | 126840196.5805 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Money Market | 3M | 34510269.2820345 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | 1Y | 784862506.199867 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | Inf | 35847481.4481261 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Guarantees Issued | 1Y | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Over Draft | 1Y | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Investment | 1Y | 12611360.8837044 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Investment | Inf | 18324428.2383007 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Bond Senior | 1Y | 3218721.44708836 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Bond Senior | 5.5Y | 16214789.0762881 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Total Exposure | 1Y | 61922330.3734412 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | 1Y | 887568667.12561 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | Inf | 88616749.299263 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| UnsignedExpo | 1Y | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Treasury | 1Y | 156798592.511412 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Money Market | 1W | 34376291.5741296 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Money Market | 1M | 79754205.0821452 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Money Market | 3M | 118497267.312187 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | 1Y | 93298935.8880307 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | Inf | 40336015.7818662 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Guarantees Issued | 1Y | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Over Draft | 1Y | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Investment | 1Y | 6136794.35933319 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Investment | Inf | 29273009.6458268 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Bond Senior | 1Y | 32129960.5494631 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| Bond Senior | 5.5Y | 7750546.55290664 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA | 3+ |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA | 3+ | A | A1 | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | 1Y | 96333197.1475847 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | Inf | 30390748.5923403 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | 1Y | 148552579.860602 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | Inf | 130716081.77009 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| Over Draft | 1Y | 0 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | 1Y | 25999064.83092 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | Inf | 6595013.64393004 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | 1Y | 154870082.260809 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| Commercial | Inf | 100453898.957276 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerB | 3 |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerB | 3 |  | A2 | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerB |  |  |  | 51 |
| All | 1Y | 16491288.6087766 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| All | Inf | 2472355.74665353 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Investment | 1Y | 32314300.9405387 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Investment | Inf | 67131490.8304831 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Bond Senior | 1Y | 4336071.84047384 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Bond Senior | 5.5Y | 3074577.78883941 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Bond Senior | 10.5Y | 20408043.916635 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| All | 1Y | 10448193.178791 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| All | Inf | 56881298.8618535 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Investment | 1Y | 2007532.20869549 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Investment | Inf | 5373840.76691889 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Bond Senior | 1Y | 27431454.1143082 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Bond Senior | 5.5Y | 64748560.2235789 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| Bond Senior | 10.5Y | 62423495.1756199 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerC | 4+ |  |  | 116 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerC | 4+ |  |  | 116 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerA |  |  |  | 51 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | CustomerC |  |  |  | 116 |

Comment: You can use a list, in witch you insert a table, and then filter your table by customer from the list

Comment: Can you show a small sample of data for 2 or 3 customers and the expected output from that sample data. This is probably simple to do but hard to describe without data to work from.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, I've added the desired output and the required sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. The simplest ( which might not be quite suitable for you if you need that exact layout), would be do to it all in a single table, group by customer and then the instrument and time band columns, then put some blank rows between the groups, at the end of the customer group you can put the `MAX()` expressions in to get your rating summary.

The layout looks like this..

[image]

And the report runs, it looks like this... (I threw this togther in a few mins so not pretty! :) )

[image]

The other way to do this would be to create a simple table that groups by customer and then insert two tablix controls within each group.

It's hard to describe the process but start with the outer table with just a simple group by customer.

The outer tablix is selected in the following screen shot, the row groups below belong to this tablix.

[image]

I added a few blank rows and then in one of the cells, right-clicked and did "Insert -> Table"

The next two images show the first and second tablix, again the row groups show relate to the selected tablix.

[image]

[image]

When we run the report we get the following...

[image]

If you are struggling, let me know and I will share the rdl files somewhere for you to download.

Comment: Appreciate you taking your time to post this detailed solution. Could you also share the rdl file as you mentioned.

Comment: This link will Expire 1st June. Both RDL files are here. All you will need to do is fix the datasource to point to any valid database connection. The dataset queries do not create any permanent data anywhere so it will not affect your database. https://1drv.ms/f/s!Al1Kq21dFT1ik8oRj3JFJsHX8pWhlg?e=dfa0VI

Comment: Thanks @alan for the solution and the .rdl files. This is exactly what I was looking for. It works 100%. And also thanks for the trick of using temp tables in the query. Never thought of it before.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. You can use whatever you like in the dataset queries as long at it returns a single result set. I often have long scripts in the report doing all the hard work but temp tables or even table variables are good for testing and easier to share on places like StackOverflow